# Getting unexpected failures running netperf. Any idea what causes them?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

I am getting

```
tjcw:Downloads$ grep netserver run-all-6.txt
+ netserver_pid=623321
+ netserver -p 50000 -4
Starting netserver with host 'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '50000' and family AF_INET
+ netserver_pid=623938
+ netserver -p 50001 -4
Starting netserver with host 'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '50001' and family AF_INET
+ netserver_pid=624493
+ netserver -p 50002 -4
Starting netserver with host 'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '50002' and family AF_INET
+ netserver_pid=624680
+ netserver -p 50003 -4
Unable to start netserver with  'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '50003' and family AF_INET
+ netserver_pid=624805
+ netserver -p 50004 -4
Unable to start netserver with  'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '50004' and family AF_INET
+ netserver_pid=624892
+ netserver -p 50005 -4
Unable to start netserver with  'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '50005' and family AF_INET
```

i.e. 3 normal starts followed by 3 failures
What does the failure message mean ?
My test case is https://github.com/tjcw/bpf-examples/blob/tjcw-integration-1.2/AF_XDP-filter/run-all.sh
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 fully updated.

Answer (score 0):

This was because instances of netserver from previous runs were still around. To terminate a netserver in a controlled way, it is necessary to start it with

```
netserver -D -f &
```

then you can record its PID and terminate it with `kill` when it is time to do that.